# AWS Lambda Function URL use token-based authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, request

I have an AWS Lambda function that I want to invoke from another service using a URL. Normally, I'd do this using an API Gateway with an authorization token. However, the execution of my Lambda regularly exceeds the [29 seconds max execution time of the API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html), making it impractical to use.

Now it is possible to assign a URL to a Lambda function, but the only available authentication is using an IAM user. Using this IAM user (unnecessarily) complicates sending the HTTP request to the Lambda URL.

**So I was wondering whether there is a way to use the Lambda Function URL and authenticate using a *single authentication token* in the request?**

An ideal request would look similar to this:

```bash
curl https://<url_id>.lambda-url.<aws_region>.on.aws/
   -H "Accept: application/json"
   -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"
```

Of course it would also be possible to make the URL public and hard-code this authentication in the Lambda handler, but I don't feel like this is the proper way to do so.

Comment: Available auth types for Lambda function URLs are IAM and none. Note that you can also directly invoke a Lambda function (in sync or async mode) via any AWS SDK but that would effectively require you to use IAM auth as well. Alternatively, perhaps using API Gateway with [async invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html) would work for you, to work around the 29 second issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question: Usually, when you are making callouts using AWS Lambda function, you would create environment variables to store the client credentials (access token) and then use them later in code. I think you can also use the parameter **"Authentication: Bearer : {access token>I think  "** in the following code segment below the environment variable screen shot below:
[image]

> Here's Python code to make the OAuth request to get the new access (Bearer) token.

```
payload={"client_id" : client_id,"client_secret" : client_secret,"grant_type" : "client_credentials"}

response = requests.request("POST", "https://api-stage.{somedomain}.com/oauth2/v1/token", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps(payload))

token_response=json.loads(response.text)
```

> Here's the code that uses the new access (Bearer) token to make the request:

```
url="https://api-stage.{somedomain}.com/comm/retail/digitalhub/xmb/v2/Prices/Matrix?udcId="+str(x)
get_response = requests.request("GET", url, headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+str(token_response['access_token'])
})
```

I hope this answers your question.